# How do I add value to an erc20 token already deployed?

Tags: solidity, remix

The contract is 0x1b016Ac4De0996b1f59EaB9c54A083aF496C811D.

For now my token shows no value. I would like each token to start from a value of 0.0001 Eth.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "add value", in order to get an useful answer please provide sufficient information of your problem and what you want to do.

Comment: For now my token show no value. I would like each token to start from a value of 0.0001 Eth. Thanks Jaime

Comment: Create a community. Give the token some utility. Anyone can create an ERC20 token; its value is derived from the project that surrounds it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying Joe, it’s obvious that these are the next steps. What my question was is if I can input a standard starting value of my token. Like, when I will deploy a crowdsale can I add value/token so whenever someone send eth to that address it will return tokens automatically?

Comment: @PatruDouazeci Such a crowdsale still would not immediately give the token value. Value is derived from people buying and selling at that price. Only buying is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

The contract you are providing does not allow buying or selling tokens, only transferences. Therefore there is no price to be set.

The [example of a token](https://ethereum.org/token) in ethereum.org implements buying and selling of tokens, you may want to take a look at that.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sample crowdsale contract on the official site](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale)

There's a function with no name that has the `payable` modifier:

```
/**
 * Fallback function
 *
 * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
 */
function () payable {
    require(!crowdsaleClosed);
    uint amount = msg.value;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
    amountRaised += amount;
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
}
```

This function is executed when somebody sends ETH to your contract:

- `msg.sender` contains the address that sent the ETH
- `msg.value` contains the amount sent by `msg.sender` to your smart contract, in wei